# Any iPhone free app could convert *.wmv file to *.MP4?

Tags: iphone, applications

I'm using mobile more often than notebook, so would like to have an app converting videos.

Comment: did you mean .webm files? Have you tried the online sites such as Zamzar?

Comment: @MrU sorry for the typo

Comment: Might be better on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, but it's valid here.

Comment: Can you just use an online video converter? I don't think iPhones support .wmv

Comment: @JohnRamos VLC etc support playing wmv files but not converting

Comment: @athos Looked a little harder and found something, posted it as an answer! Tell my if it helps or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "The Video Converter," an iPad and iPhone app, that promises to convert files including .WMV files to formats like .MP4.

Download [The Video Converter](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-converter-convert-your/id893347665?mt=8)

Comment: Seems there's no free converter app

Comment: @athos it seems that way to me. Glad this helped you though.